# How to check portion of a string and accept anything after it?

Tags: php, jquery, json

I had a hard time wording this question. Lets say you have two things in a database:

-"String"

-"Stringify"

In PHP, you use this:
"SELECT * WHERE string = stri%"

This would return both of the strings in the database because the **%** [percentage sign] is the responsible one for checking if the values have those four letters [stri] and accepting them since the rest doesn't matter.

---

That's not the question. Is there something like that **[%]** in jQuery?

I have the following code.

```
if (ext == "jpg" || ext == "gif") {
} else {
   ext = ext + ".jpg";
}
```

Many times, my JSON might return something like this:

nameofimage.**jpg?1**

This is ignored because **jpg?1** is **NOT** equals to **jpg** but it is still a jpg. This is why I am asking... Is there anything that can be used to check only the first three letters of the extension and ignore the rest?

Something like this:

```
if (ext == "jpg%" || ext == "gif%") {
//Do nothing, it's already a jpg or a gif
} else {
   ext = ext + ".jpg";
}
```

I tried my very best to word this the right way. I hope someone here can help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [string.contains()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/contains)

```
if(ext.contains(".jpg") || ext.contains(".gif")) {
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the method you are looking for is indexOf():

```
if (ext.indexOf('jpg') !== -1 || ext.indexOf('gif') !== -1) {
    // true
}
```

However it is a bit cleaner and safer to not just check for the extension but the whole filename as well. Imagine this filename: "somejpg.exe". The above method would consider it as a "jpg" where as it is not. The easiest to use regular expressions for these kind of things:

```
/\.(jpg|gif|png|bmp)$/.test('test.png'); // => true
/\.(jpg|gif|png|bmp)$/.test('test.gif'); // => true
/\.(jpg|gif|png|bmp)$/.test('hack_jpg.exe'); // => false
```

Comment: You should probably test for the index being `0`, as he wants the `jpg` to be at the beginning of the extension.